# Cannot start publishing my Google App Script as Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a Google App Script, which is bound to Document. But now I need to publish this script as an Add-on for our domain.

In order to publish the add-on, I have read the documentation below:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish#development_checklist

As described in this article, I registered a version of my script through "Manage Version".
**But when I go to the "Publish" menu of the script editor, I only have the option "Deploy as web-app". I do not see any menu item "Deploy as add-on".**

How can I start the publishing process for my App Script?

Comment: After submitting the form, have you received confirmation from Google that you're Script has been accepted for publishing, and that they will allow you to place it on the Add-on store?

Answer (score 0):

Before you can publish an add-on you must go through the application and review process:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish#apply_to_publish

The "Deploy as add-on" option will only appear after you are approved.

Answer (score 0):

To deploy your add-on, you have to first get approval from the Apps Script Advisor. To do this you have to go to:

[The Publishing Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish)

Then you have to fill out the Google Form there.

Hope this helps!

Notice: It might take a few weeks before they respond back to you!

Answer (score -1):

The reason you are not able to see that "Deploy as add-on" option because, you might be opening the normal Apps script console(script.google.com).

But if you want to publish your script code as an add-on, you have to open the script editor from the Doc or sheet which is bound to the script.

1. Open the Doc, Tools--> Script editor.
2. Then go to Publish, now you can see an option for "Deploy as add-on".

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But it is already what I do, for opening the Script Editor. I open it from inside the container Doc, and I do not have "Deploy as add-on".